# Combining boolean operations over multiple columns among different dataframes using reduce

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes as below

```
af=pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,7]})

bf=pd.DataFrame({'B': [5, 2], 'C': [1, 4],'D':[6,8]})
```

I want to perform this operation

```
(af['A']>bf['B'])|(af['A']>bf['C'])|(af['A']>bf['D'])
```

I  believe there would be an easier way to this using **reduce** higher order function, iterating over columns of bf and folding the individual results into a single column, but I am not sure how to proceed

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first calculate the minimum for the `bf` over the `B`, `C` and `D` columns:

```
af['A'] > bf[['B', 'C', 'D']].min(axis=1)
```

Indeed, given that `af['A']` is greater than the minimum of the other columns for that row, we know that at least one element in these columns is less than the value for `af['A']`.